# Javascript selectbox with div instead of textarea

Tags: javascript

I have a select box which writes the selection into a textarea.

This code works good with a textarea:

```
<input name="aktuelles_titel" id="aktuelles_titel" value="<?php echo $row_RS_Aktuelles_und_Produktneuheiten['titel']; ?>">
<div name="aktuelles_inhalt" id="aktuelles_inhalt"><?php echo $row_RS_Aktuelles_und_Produktneuheiten['inhalt']; ?>"</div>
<input name="badetraeume_titel" id="badetraeume_titel" value="<?php echo $row_RS_Badetraeume['titel']; ?>">
<div name="badetraeume_inhalt" id="badetraeume_inhalt"><?php echo $row_RS_Badetraeume['inhalt']; ?>"</div>
<form id="teaserDetails">
<select name="teaser" onchange="setTeaser(document.Form, this.value);">
<option value="">Teaser auswählen ...</option>
<option value="1"><?php echo $row_RS_Aktuelles_und_Produktneuheiten['titel']; ?></option>
<option value="2"><?php echo $row_RS_Badetraeume['titel']; ?></option>
</select>
<textarea disabled="disabled" name="showteaser" type="text" id="showteaser" value="."> </textarea>
</form>


<script>
var teaserInhalt = {
'1': document.getElementById('aktuelles_inhalt').innerHTML,
'2': document.getElementById('badetraeume_inhalt').innerHTML
};
var form = document.getElementById('teaserDetails');
form.elements.teaser.onchange = function () {
var form = this.form;
form.elements.showteaser.value = teaserInhalt[this.value];
};
</script>
```

But when the textarea is changed to a div container, the javascript does not work. I searched a lot, changed a lot, but no luck. I do this for the first time, I think I miss something small.

This code has a fault:

```
<input name="aktuelles_titel" id="aktuelles_titel" value="<?php echo $row_RS_Aktuelles_und_Produktneuheiten['titel']; ?>">
<div name="aktuelles_inhalt" id="aktuelles_inhalt"><?php echo $row_RS_Aktuelles_und_Produktneuheiten['inhalt']; ?>"</div>
<input name="badetraeume_titel" id="badetraeume_titel" value="<?php echo $row_RS_Badetraeume['titel']; ?>">
<div name="badetraeume_inhalt" id="badetraeume_inhalt"><?php echo $row_RS_Badetraeume['inhalt']; ?>"</div>
<form id="teaserDetails">
<select name="teaser" onchange="setTeaser(document.Form, this.value);">
<option value="">Teaser auswählen ...</option>
<option value="1"><?php echo $row_RS_Aktuelles_und_Produktneuheiten['titel']; ?></option>
<option value="2"><?php echo $row_RS_Badetraeume['titel']; ?></option>
</select>
<div id="showteaser"> </div>
</form>


<script>
var teaserInhalt = {
'1': document.getElementById('aktuelles_inhalt').innerHTML,
'2': document.getElementById('badetraeume_inhalt').innerHTML
};
var form = document.getElementById('teaserDetails');
form.elements.teaser.onchange = function () {
var form = this.form;
form.elements.showteaser.value = teaserInhalt[this.value];
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.getElementById('showteaser').html = teaserInhalt[this.value];
```

instead of

```
form.elements.showteaser.value = teaserInhalt[this.value];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:
    `form.elements.showteaser.value`

try replace value with `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Change in your script..

```
    <script>
    var teaserInhalt = {
    '1': document.getElementById('aktuelles_inhalt').innerHTML,
    '2': document.getElementById('badetraeume_inhalt').innerHTML
    };
    var form = document.getElementById('teaserDetails');
    form.elements.teaser.onchange = function () {
     // this change made in your script.   
    document.getElementById('showteaser').innerHTML = teaserInhalt[this.value];

    };
    </script>
```

Comment: The .innerHMTL was it. First it did not work because I just pasted the code without thinking and the line var form = this.form; was missing.